# How to add a column in table via stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-11g, plsql, alter-table

```
create or replace procedure SP_PARAMETER_TEST -- this is my table
(
       NAME_KEY in VARCHAR2 -- this contains a value assume NAME_KEY contains "Gypsum"
) 
is
begin
  ALTER TABLE PARAMETER_TEST ADD NAME_KEY VARCHAR(2);
end SP_PARAMETER_TEST;
```

I want to add the column which has text value "Gypsum". But I am getting errors. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed DDL in a stored procedure like this.

Either use `execute immediate` and your DDL statement passed to it as a string, or, better, remove the stored procedure entirely an execute the DDL directly.